# What is FirewallD?

Tags: 16.04, internet, firewall, settings, wired

I'm trying to activate the firewall on my wired internet connection, but it says FirewallD is not running. Is that something I can turn on through ufw? I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

Firewalld is a front end for iptables and is the default firewall used in RHEL (Centos) and Fedora so my guess is you are reading RHEL/Fedora documentation rather than Ubuntu documentation ?

See https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Firewalld?rd=FirewallD and http://www.firewalld.org/

I am sure it is available as source code but I have not tried to install it on Ubuntu.

By default, Ubuntu uses ufw - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

For a graphical front end you can use gufw - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Gufw

In general to activate your firewall on Ubuntu you would :

```
sudo ufw enable
```

Is there something more than that information you need ?

For Ubuntu see the wiki - https://help.ubuntu.com/ and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommunityHelpWiki

Comment: fyi:  Anna,  ufw is the ubuntu frontend for iptables; so ufw & firewalld do the same thing (ie. simplify iptables for people that don't want to mess with commands)

Answer (score 0):

`UFW` and `Firewalld` are both front end for `iptable` manipulation on Ubuntu and REHL systems. They both can be installed on Ubuntu systems and used accordingly. I suggest you enable `UFW`on your Ubuntu by running:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

but if you desire to use `Firewalld` then install by running ( note the terminal command tool is `firewall-cmd`:

```
sudo apt install firewalld
```

Want the GUI aspect then install the GUI interface with:

```
sudo apt install firewall-config
sudo apt install firewall-applet
```

More information:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall

http://www.firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewall-cmd.html

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ufw-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands